# Which predictive modelling technique will be most helpful?

Tags: neural-network, regression, linear-regression, data-analysis, random-forest

I have a training dataset which gives me the ranking of various cricket players(2008) on the basis of their performance in the past years(2005-2007).

I've to develop a model using this data and then apply it on another dataset to predict the ranking of players(2012) using the data already given to me(2009-2011).

Which predictive modelling will be best for this? What are the pros and cons of using the different forms of regression or neural networks?

Answer (score 2):

The type of model to use depends on different factors:

- Amount of data: if you have very little data, you better opt for a simple prediction model like linear regression. If you use a prediction model which is too powerful you run into the risk of over-fitting your model with the effect that it generalizes bad on new data. Now you might ask, what is little data? That depends on the number of input dimensions and on the underlying distributions of your data.
- Your experience with the model. Neural networks can be quite tricky to handle if you have little experience with them. There are quite a few parameters to be optimized, like the network layer structure, the number of iterations, the learning rate, the momentum term, just to mention a few. Linear prediction is a lot easier to handle with respect to this "meta-optimization"

A pragmatic approach for you, if you still cannot opt for one of the methods, would be to evaluate a couple of different prediction methods. You take some of your data where you already have target values (the 2008 data), split it into training and test data (take some 10% as test data, e.g.), train and test using cross-validation and compute the error rate by comparing the predicted values with the target values you already have.

One great book, which is also on the web, is *Pattern recognition and machine learning* by C. Bishop. It has a great introductory section on prediction models.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Which predictive modelling will be best for this? 2. What are the pros
>      and cons of using the different forms of regression or neural
>      networks?

1. "What is best" depends on the resources you have.  Full Bayesian Networks (or k-Dependency Bayesian Networks) with information theoretically learned graphs, are the ultimate 'assumptionless' models, and often perform extremely well. Sophisticated Neural Networks can perform impressively well too.  The problem with such models is that they can be very computationally expensive, so models that employ methods of approximation may be more appropriate. There are mathematical similarities connecting regression, neural networks and bayesian networks.
2. Regression is actually a simple form of Neural Networks with some additional assumptions about the data. Neural Networks can be constructed to make less assumptions about the data, but as Thomas789 points out at the cost of being considerably more difficult to understand (sometimes monumentally difficult to debug).

As a rule of thumb - the more assumptions and approximations in a model the easier it is to A: understand and B: find the computational power necessary, but potentially at the cost of performance or "overfitting" (this is when a model suits the training data well, but doesn't extrapolate to the general case).

Free online books:

http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/

http://ciml.info/dl/v0_8/ciml-v0_8-all.pdf